# Iterate through list in an html script

Tags: javascript, python, html, loops, cgi

I have a list in a CGI file as follows:

`my_list = [apple, oranges, grapes, berries]`

I want to iterate through this list in my html code. So far I have this:

```
<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">
<!--

document.write('<table border="0" cellspacing="0">')

for(i=0; i <= %d; i++) {
    document.write('<tr height="50">')
    for (j=0; j <3; j++) {document.write('<td width="250" align="center" style="border- top-style:none;border-right-style:none;border-left-style:none;border-bottom- style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:black;"> '+%s+ '</td>')}
    document.write('</tr>')
}

document.write('</table>')

//-->
</SCRIPT>
...
</html>'''%(len(my_list), my_list)
```

for each column this prints out apple, oranges, grapes, berries | apple, oranges, grapes, berries and etc.

I want this to print out for the first column

- apple
- oranges
- grapes
- berries

Then I have another list for the second column and another list for the third column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you can do everything in JS once you pass the data in from Python.

If the lists are all the same length here is a plunker for a simplified way of doing that shows how this can be done. http://plnkr.co/edit/0yGwiJXCLQeADL0K7DlJ?p=preview

If the lists can be different sizes I created another plunker to show you how that could be done. http://plnkr.co/edit/jabIJwqvufDaZkX3685D?p=preview

This should be enough to get you started.

Comment: do you know how I can go about to adding links to each text: I tried this code: {document.write('<td width="250" align="center" style="border-top-style:none;border-right-style:none;border-left-style:none;border-bottom-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:black;"> ''<a href="website+%s[i]"></a>'+%s[i]+'</td>')}...is this valid?

Comment: that doesn't look right to me. I have no idea what `code`website+%s[i]`code` from the snippet you provided.

Comment: Also it looks like you are really trying to mix your python script with your JS code. I think you should just pass the data into JS as list or object and then do everything in JS.

Comment: I tried to iterate through my list thus I used %s[i]